# How to create a Dashboard specific to user stories in TFS -Azure Devops

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

How to create a Dashboard specific to user stories in TFS -Azure Devops - I am looking for graphical representation of User stories against the entire  sprint cycle - Like i have  11 sprints and  140 user stories so i wanted to see User stories fall under current sprint and  completed sprints along with there states and sprints which are not started will show blank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could create a query to list all user stories->save it as shared query->click the tab **Chart**->click the button **new Chart** and select **Stacked bar**->configure the chart and then add the chart to Dashboard.

Result:

[image]